# Is it possible to use Global Static variables in Storm Bolts/Spout in actual cluster environment

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have a Storm project, with Topology Class having main method to submit topology, Spout1 --> Bolt1, Spout2 --> Bolt2. I have another final util class which has a static variable --> a List of Strings. Now Bolt1 uses this static list and prints out the content, where as Bolt2 adds String in the list. Both Spout1 and Spout2 are emitting messages to the respective bolts, at an interval of 1000ms and 500ms respectively.

**I have set the number of workers as 4, i.e. Config.setNumWorkers(4).**

**Parallelism Hint : Spout1 - 1, Bolt1 - 100, Spout2 - 1, Bolt2 - 100.**

This code setup is working in LocalCluster Mode in my Window machine.

But I am not sure if this will work on actual cluster environment in linux, with multiple servers catering Supervisor deamon. In actual cluster environment i suppose workers will run in different machines with different JVM processes. **Then will it be possible for bolts to access the Global Static Variable, i.e. List of Strings as they can do it in local cluster ?**

Below goes some code for reference :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Starting Topology....");
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("spout12", new TestSpout2(), 1);
    builder.setBolt("bolt12", new TestBolt2(), 100).shuffleGrouping("spout12", "spout12Stream");
    builder.setSpout("spout11", new TestSpout1(), 1);
    builder.setBolt("bolt11", new TestBolt1(), 100).shuffleGrouping("spout11", "spout11Stream");

    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(false);
    conf.setNumWorkers(4);
    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();

    cluster.submitTopology("TestTopology3", conf, builder.createTopology());

}


Spout1 :
public void nextTuple() {
    int a = (int) (((Math.random() * 10)+1)*((Math.random() * 10)+1));
    String str = String.valueOf(a);
    Utils.sleep(1000);
    collector.emit("spout11Stream", new Values(str), str);
}


Bolt1 : 
public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
    System.out.println("########## In execute of TestBolt11....\t Value 0 : " + tuple.getString(0) + "\t\t List : "
            + CommonUtils.list);
    _collector.ack(tuple);
}


Spout2 : 
public void nextTuple() {
    int a = (int) (((Math.random() * 10)+1)*((Math.random() * 10)+1));
    String str = String.valueOf(a);
    Utils.sleep(500);
    collector.emit("spout12Stream", new Values(str), str);
}


Bolt2 : 
public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!! In execute of TestBolt12....\t Value 0 : " + tuple.getString(0));
    CommonUtils.list.add(tuple.getString(0)+"gb");
    _collector.ack(tuple);
}


CommonUtilis class : 
public final class CommonUtils {
public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Sysout on successfull run :

```
 !!!!!!!!!!!!! In execute of TestBolt12....  Value 0 : 31
 !!!!!!!!!!!!! In execute of TestBolt12....  Value 0 : 9
 !!!!!!!!!!!!! In execute of TestBolt12....  Value 0 : 68
 !!!!!!!!!!!!! In execute of TestBolt12....  Value 0 : 24
 ########## In execute of TestBolt11....     Value 0 : 39        List : [31gb, 9gb, 68gb, 24gb]
 !!!!!!!!!!!!! In execute of TestBolt12....  Value 0 : 60
 !!!!!!!!!!!!! In execute of TestBolt12....  Value 0 : 30
 ########## In execute of TestBolt11....     Value 0 : 26        List : [31gb, 9gb, 68gb, 24gb, 60gb, 30gb]
 !!!!!!!!!!!!! In execute of TestBolt12....  Value 0 : 9
 !!!!!!!!!!!!! In execute of TestBolt12....  Value 0 : 15
 ########## In execute of TestBolt11....     Value 0 : 11        List : [31gb, 9gb, 68gb, 24gb, 60gb, 30gb, 9gb, 15gb]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, static variable access is scoped by JVM and you'll have several JVM's as you point out.

There are some work-arounds, tho:

1. You can have a bolt with parallelism hint of 1 that accesses the static variable.  Since there's only one bolt, access happens in only one JVM, but then again, you might as well just use an instance variable on that bolt.
2. A variation on (1) is to use a scheduler implementation in storm to have multiple instances of your bolt, but all allocated to the same worker.  This approach is not something I've tried, but I thought I'd throw it out there anyway.
3. You can use a database, relational or NoSQL, as a read/write store for data that's spread across the cluster
4. You can store the list in zookeeper.  I'd wrap the zookeeper access in a singleton class so as to make your bolt implementation simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the info. My actual problem is i have 100 bolts, each reading a line of String and picking our certain text based on list of regex.Now this list of regex keeps on changing from another web application. So since Static Variable are not an option here, all my 100 bolts need to have their own cache. But how can i update the cache of these 100 bolts without fail simultaneously.
1. All Grouping is an option, but is there any other way around, simpler, since i don't want to keep the same cache at 100 bolts, it's just gonna make them heavier.

Comment: DB interaction will make bolt operation slow. therefore i can't use DB to get the list of regex everytime.